# Blazor server side and modules in seperate projects

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm searching for help with blazor and modular apps.
What i want to have as a example

- Main app (blazor project)
- Module UserManagment (Razor library)
- Module CRM (Razor library)

and I want to make that the modules will comunicate between us.

Question, how to make it ? Each module as a blazor app with sub project razor library, or can I make one blazor app, and then create only components in razor library and bind it in some way to parent app?

Comment: As your sample it looks good for me. You can follow my sample at https://github.com/aguacongas/football-championship

Comment: but what in case if i want to have more then one blazor project, example each module (user management, CRM, ...) should have his own left side menu etc, and possibility to work as stand alone apps. How should the comunication look like betwean this ?

Comment: You can have the number of razor libraries of your choice. Blazor can contains components and services you want to use in your Blazor app. You can use a singleton service  you inject in each components to send message to other components

Comment: but how the routing should look. If i have 5 blazor projects in one solution?

Comment: I don't think it will break the routing. But I've not tested it yet on several project.

Comment: Read this : [Route to components from multiple assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#route-to-components-from-multiple-assemblies)

Comment: thx this is working fine :)
only one thing i don't know how to solve a problem if i want to have app Like CRM and in page directive i need to insert always "/CRM/xxx"
is possible to make the page ony as "/xxx" and the project will give from his self the info about CRM?

Comment: Probably with the good routing configuration : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: and what do You think about latest razor libpages and views option and areas in app? will be this better opttion do do things that i want ?

Comment: It could be a good option. But if you want to share your modules with other projets may be not.

Comment: @Krzysztof did you find the right way? I have same need